# tailwind arbitrary value class specificity issue

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, styling

I'm using tailwindcss 3.3.3 and having an issue with tailwind arbitrary value specificity that it does not override the generic value.
For example, I have this element `<div className="w-full w-[80px]">Sample</div>`.
I expect that div will have 80px width but I got width 100% is taking precedence over width 80px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an arbitrary variant to force the 80px width to apply.

```
<div className="w-full [&]:w-[80px]">Sample</div>
```

Comment: [Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/nBLpxkxddZ)

Comment: I think it should be default behaviour that arbitrary value will always take precedence, because it was before I upgrade to 3.3.3

Comment: @QuocVanTang That doesn't seem to be the case in the playground with version set to 2.2.19 (https://play.tailwindcss.com/KGtbysyBUP), but regardless this is a workaround.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, it seems that my understanding is wrong. So it means that tailwind didn't care about arbitrary value or generic value, is it correct?

Comment: @QuocVanTang It's not that it doesn't care, but that it doesn't override other classes that style the same property. But you can override it by means of using `[&]:w-[80px]`, as shown.

Comment: Unmitigated, do you know any libraries or plugins that always make arbitrary value class (e.g w-[80px], py-[2px], leading-[1]...) always take precedence to the generic value (e.g w-full, py-2, leading-none...)

Comment: @QuocVanTang No, I am not aware of a plugin for that. Are you unable to change the className value?

Comment: Yes, it's not too easy to add prefix or important to the class (e.g !w-[80px]) in my case. Because I got a wrong assumption that the arbitrary value always take precedence so my React element usually got 2 tailwind class target the same property (e.g w-full in the base component, w-[80px] is the className props append to the base specifically).

Answer (score 1):

The [tailwind-unimportant](https://github.com/mwnciau/tailwindcss-unimportant) plugin for Tailwind also solves this problem. It adds a variant that allows the classes to be overridden. Your example would become:

```html
<div className="-:w-full w-[80px]">Sample</div>
```

The `-:` makes `w-full` have a lower specificity than your arbitrary value class (and all other utility classes). This is useful when making components, as you can use the variant in one place (in the component), and the rest of your code can use the normal Tailwind classes.